# Phone number in header isn't clickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tel

I know enfold offers the option to put your phone number above the header, but I want to actually put a larger number in the header itself. I have already done this, but for some reason mobile phones will not recognize the phone number as a clickable link. Here is the code:

```
$phone = avia_get_option('phone');
                        $phone_class = !empty($nav) ? "with_nav" : "";
                        if($phone) echo "<div class='phone-info {$phone_class}'><span>{$phone}</span></div>";

                        /* <div class="phone2">503-436-5584</div>
                        *  Hook that can be used for plugins and theme extensions (currently:  the woocommerce shopping cart)
                        */
                        do_action('avia_meta_header');
                    echo '</nav>';
                ?>
              </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

        <div  id='header_main' class='container_wrap container_wrap_logo'>
           <div class='phone2'><a href="tel:503-436-5582">503-436-5582</a></div>
               </a></strong><img class='cards' src='http://garagedoorsrepairwestlinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/crdit-card-logo.jpg' /></div>   
                <?php
                /*
                * Hook that can be used for plugins and theme extensions (currently:  the woocommerce shopping cart)
                */
                do_action('ava_main_header');

                ?>
```

what am I doing wrong? when I add the second `</div>` it shows up as a link on the computer but it completely takes the logo and number off.

Comment: *add second div. also disregard the mismatched phone numbers, i already fixed that and it didn't do anything.

Comment: You post PHP code but have not tagged the question with “php”. Either specify why you think the PHP code is relevant, or post the HTML code generated, together with any relevant CSS code if needed to present code that actually reproduces the problem. Also specify the browser(s) tested.

Comment: it's relevant because that's the code for adding a phone number to a header. That is the relevant css code, and browsers tested are firefox, IE, safari, and chrome.

Comment: You should show HTML and CSS code that actually reproduce the problem and also correct errors already pointed out – the question should be fully understandable without reading the comments. Only after knowing which HTML and CSS trigger the issue does it become relevant to look the PHP code that generates them, if that’s relevant. You wrote “That is the relevant css code”, but there is no CSS code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is not working because of the '-' characters in the phone number. You should try and change to: `<a href="tel:5034365582">503-436-5582</a>`

By the way, I recommend using the callto protocol, which will open skype on a desktop and the phone application on smartphones:

```
<a href="callto://5034365582" title="Call Me">503-436-5582</a>
```

Comment: i've tried both with the - and without and still nothing :/